# How to map complex models

Tags: automapper, flatten

I have a source model that looks like this:

```
public class FooBar {
    public Foo foo {get;set;}
    public Bar bar {get;set;|
}

public class Foo {
    // tons of properties
}

public class Bar {
    // tons of irrelevant properties
    public Baz baz {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have a destination model that flattens FooBar into NewFooBar and looks like this:

```
public class NewFooBar {
    // all properties from Foo
    public Baz baz {get;set;}
}
```

How can I map FooBar to NewFooBar without having to individually map all of foo's properties?  (there are many of them).

My first solution was to Map Foo and Bar seperately to NewFooBar, and that works.  Then perform the maps individually.  But this seems kludgy.  I'd rather do it in a single mapping if possible.  Am I missing some simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, NewFooBar>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.Ignore())
            ;

Mapper.CreateMap<FooBar, NewFooBar>()
    .ConvertUsing(src => {
        var newFooBar = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Foo, NewFooBar>(src.foo);

        newFooBar.baz = src.bar.baz;

        return newFooBar;
    });
    ;
```

and then

```
var newFooBar = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<FooBar, NewFooBar>(fooBar);
```

Comment: Well, that's not much better, and arguably more complex than simply performing two maps.  But it's an interesting thought.

Comment: The CreateMap is done once in one place. The idea is to keep the Map succinct which in this case it is, just like any other map i.e. one doesn't have to remember to two maps every time.

Comment: That's a good point.  And in this case, i think you're right.  However, i have another situation that I asked about in a different question.. would you mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091653/how-to-introduce-additional-data-into-destination-mapping-without-changing-sourc